# ERROR 401 on creation of External (Internal) Master Instance on GCP Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I started the creation of a MySQL 1st Gen read replica with Google Cloud SQL. However after 5 hours of waiting I have given up. Now I can't delete the instance and on trying to delete using the cloud terminal just get

I gave up and deleted the project...

Meanwhile back to the first part of the script -

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"name": "food22",
    "region": "us-central1",
    "databaseVersion": "MYSQL_5_5",
    "onPremisesConfiguration": {"hostPort": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306"}}' -X POST 
\
https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[Project ID]/instances
```

[Orange Warning Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN8AS.png)

I have a nasty feeling that Google have abandoned this on premise link after I saw this - https://serverfault.com/questions/835108/gcp-configure-an-external-master-issue/835266 and looked at Answer Two.....

Come on Google - get your act together!